# Creating add transaction and seal block from mix localhost on button click

Tags: mix, ethereum-wallet-dapp

When we open mix we have 3 windows. The first shows contract, the second shows the front end and the third shows the blocks and transaction while we create a new block or approve transaction.

How can I create a buttons in the second window in order that, when clicking on "add", transaction blocks are added and transaction are approved without the need to go in the third window to click on the plus sign and manually approve pending transaction ?

Comment: Can you please re-read your question, check for proper spelling, grammer and interpunctuation, and edit it to clarify what your specific issue is. It's really hard to tell what you are asking there.

Comment: @5chdn Kindly check now . This is best i could explain

Comment: You are saying mist but describing mix? I'm confused.

Comment: apologies its mix